# Assets wont load after renaming public folder in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel version 5.3
I renamed my public folder to public_html by add following lines to my

> AppServiceProvider

I update/renamed following code in register method.

```
public function register()
{
  $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return realpath(base_path().'/../public_html');
  });
}
```

After that any of my assets wont load i faced 404 error for all of them. what should i do now?

Comment: Check [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/laravel-51-change-name-and-location-of-public-folder) Maybe you need to make a symlink of the new folder `ln -s`

Comment: it doesnt work or me

Comment: Why would you change the app folder btw? And not use it like it is as default?

Comment: What says the 404 error? what is the path, I think you should also remove the first `/` of `/../public_html`

Comment: because on the server i have to use public_html

Comment: the urls are ok but assets file wont load

Comment: On your server put all of the applications content, including the /public folder in your public_html folder. You can change the document root with .htaccess file in the root of public_html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suggest you do not use a hosting webspace for Laravel.

VPS is cheap as heck these days, get a VPS and use Laravel Forge if you don't want to manually install the environments.

Use git to deploy your code on to the server.

Even if you solved this very problem with symlink(I don't think you have the permission), you will still encounter other problems because you won't have the permission to install composer dependencies.

By the way, what Dennis suggested would not matter I believe, it still points to the same destination.

> remove the first / of /../public_html